Update Azure Machine Learning Compute Instances with Python SDKv2
At first, I have some terraform code that will deploy compute instances for AML. But there's a lack of update of the terraform code so we can not add the option of schedules and auto shutdown. https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/20973
So for this I want to create a workaround, because terraform created compute instances will stay on until someone shut them off.
I'm trying to list all the compute instances with the python SDK V2 and update each compute instances one by one. But it does not work.
subscription_id = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx"
resource_group = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
workspace = "XXXXXXXXXXX"

from azure.ai.ml import MLClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.ai.ml.constants import TimeZone
from azure.ai.ml.entities import ComputeSchedules, ComputeStartStopSchedule, RecurrencePattern, RecurrenceTrigger

# Login (az login or env variables)
ml_client = MLClient(
    DefaultAzureCredential(), subscription_id, resource_group, workspace
)

for compute_instance in ml_client.compute.list():
    if compute_instance.type == "computeinstance":
        rec_trigger = RecurrenceTrigger(start_time="2024-01-10T00:00:00", time_zone=TimeZone.CENTRAL_EUROPEAN_STANDARD_TIME , frequency="day", interval=1, schedule=RecurrencePattern(hours=20, minutes=[0]))
        myschedule = ComputeStartStopSchedule(trigger=rec_trigger, action="stop")
        com_sch = ComputeSchedules(compute_start_stop=[myschedule])
        compute_instance.schedules = com_sch
        compute_instance.idle_time_before_shutdown = "PT30M"
        compute_instance.idle_time_before_shutdown_minutes = 30
        ml_client.begin_create_or_update(compute_instance)

I get this output Warning: 'Location' is not supported for compute type computeinstance and will not be used.. The location property is coming from the ml_client.compute.get(compute_instance.name).
I want to idle shutdown after 30 minutes and force shutdown at 8pm. For this I've started to edit one compute instance from the AML Web UI, then used the python code to get the content of this modified compute instance and replicate it for the others.
On the begin_create_or_update, I see that the compute instance is in creating state, but once updated, there's still no schedule nor idle shutdown.
I also tried with az ml compute update but there's an error on the idle argument that is not recognized even if it is in the documentation. https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/26911

I was going to open an issue on the github, but someone did it instead of me https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/35156

Yes I have raised the issue on the GitHub. You can refer it for further details.

As workaround you can set idle timeout via REST API:
Documentation with examples exactly for Azure ML Compute Instance IdleShutDown parameter - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azureml/compute/update-idle-shutdown-setting?view=rest-azureml-2024-04-01
To achieve so you can use any custom tool which can do an authorised POST request like this:
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces/{workspaceName}/computes/{computeName}/updateIdleShutdownSetting?api-version=2024-04-01-preview


With the headers for the request:

Authorization: Bearer <YOUR_TOKEN_HERE> - remember, you need to authenticate first. to get your token you can use az account get-access-token cli command.

Content-type: application/json


You can give it a try just from the documentation page as I just did and it was successful, see screenshot below with 200 response.
Also, if you need to stick to az cli, you may want to explore az rest cli, here is documentation and an example:
# Command format example for PUT
az rest --method put --url https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscriptionId>/resourceGroups/<resourceGroup>/providers/Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/<containerRegistryName>?api-version=2023-01-01-preview --body "{'location': '<locationName>', 'sku': {'name': '<skuName>'}, 'properties': {'adminUserEnabled': '<propertyValue>'}}"

Taking all this into account you can wrap details and use it in where you want, like terraform or any other tools. also, in some cases terraform az api module provider might be useful as well
Screenshot of tested approach:

